# How to view symbolicated crash logs from itunes connect, if i deleted release archive from xcode?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Is it possible to restore the archive from iTunes Connect or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Bitcode you can retrieve symbols from iTunes Connect.

Otherwise if you ticked the *Include app symbols for your application…* when uploading the IPA to iTC you might have a chance to get symbolicated symbols from Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Note that only crashes for Apps in your Organizer will be displayed but yoy can try to remake a build to make your app appear there.

N.